# how to play random video from list [web page]

Tags: javascript, video, random, playback

I have some videos (for example A,B,C,D) stored on the server and i need to play them in random order on webpage load. I also need to play the video from a random time, not from the start.

For example:

> refresh -> load video C and start playing it from 2:13
>
> refresh -> load video A and start playing it from 1:52
>
> [...]

How can I do this?

Comment: Have you done anything at all?

Comment: what don't you know? how to play a video (any video) or how to use google to search the term `js random array item` ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if we can help you in writing code from the scratch, but what I would do is, find out a JavaScript plug-in that plays videos by taking two arguments namely `URL` and `StartTime`. So, I would initialize the URLs of all the videos in an array like this:

```
var videos = [
    "movie1.mp4",
    "movie2.mp4",
    "movie3.mp4",
    "movie4.mp4",
]
```

I then use a randomize script like this:

```
var random = Math.floor((Math.random() * videos.length) + 1);
```

Now I would initialize the video this way:

```
initVideo(videos[random], Math.floor((Math.random() * 100));
```

Here I assume that the `initVideo(url, startTime)` is taken.

Comment: Thank you Praveen, my real problem is the plugin, beacuse i'm looking for something but no one support "StartTime"